# Attach a tmux session over SSH and run a command

Tags: tmux

This works to attach a session with a specified name or create if it doesn't exist:

`tmux new-session -A -s encode`

but I need to add a command to run ie.

`tmux new-session -A -s encode 'ls /home/user/'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to take a look at the `tmux send-keys` command. From the `man`

> Send a key or keys to a window.  Each argument key is the name of the key (such as `C-a` or `npage` ) to send; if the string is
>                not recognised as a key, it is sent as a series of characters.  The -l flag disables key name lookup and sends the keys liter-
>                ally.  All arguments are sent sequentially from first to last.  The -R flag causes the terminal state to be reset.

In your case you can do

```
tmux new-session -d -A -s encode
tmux send-keys -t encode 'ls /home/users' C-m
tmux attach -t encode
```

`C-m` is the Enter key. The `-d` flag is to create the session, but not attach to it.

Comment: Thanks but once I create the new-session it attaches the window making it not possible to send the send-keys command. I really need this all on one line as a ssh command. ie. `ssh servername -t "tmux -------"`

Comment: Use `tmux new-session -d` to create a session but not attach to it. Then use `tmux attach -t encode` to attach. I edited the answer above.

Comment: Also, shameless plug here, take a look at https://github.com/tonchis/tmuxify. It's a tool to create tmux sessions from a layout file where you define the windows, panes and commands.